# I changed permissions in my /home dir to 750 and files in it now I'm not able to connect the server

Tags: permissions, ssh, login, connection

I changed the `/home` dir to 750 and files in it.

Now I'm not able to connect the server with SSH public key. It’s showing the error `Permission denied (publickey)`.

Comment: Did you by any chance, chmod recursively ?

Comment: Where is your server hosted?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like the permissions have been changed recursively.

The files in the directory `~/.ssh` need very strict permissions, especially these 2 files:

```
-rw-------  1 am  402 2020-04-26 18:00 authorized_keys
-rw-------  1 am 2.6K 2020-05-13 23:56 id_rsa
```

As you can see, these files need to have permission octal 600.

To fix this, you either need physical or root access to the machine to revert the permissions to 600.

Please note that to get SSH access, the only needed file is `authorized_keys` (with permissions 600).

Also for reference, the following files should have permission octal 644:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 am  559 2020-05-13 23:56 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r--  1 am 5.0K 2021-02-27 18:02 known_hosts
```

Comment: Thank you Artur, I wonder 750 will not do the job?

Comment: -rw------- 1 autobot autobot  408 Oct  5  2018 authorized_keys
-rw-r--r-- 1 autobot autobot  222 Nov  8 09:21 known_hosts

Comment: these are the same setting for another replication server.